# clojure: Efficiently determining if a string begins with any prefix in a collection

Tags: clojure

I'm have a collection of prefix/value pairs, and wish to find any value in this connection associated with a prefix that my current target string begins with. (It is not important that behavior be defined in the case where more than one prefix matches, as the nature of my use case is such that this should never occur).

A naive (working) implementation follows:

```
(defn prefix-match [target-str pairs]
  (some
    (fn [[k v]]
        (if (.startsWith target-str k)
            v
            false))
    pairs))
```

Such that:

```
user=> (prefix-match "foobar" {"meh" :qux, "foo" :baz})
:baz
```

This works as intended, but is O(n) with the length of the `pairs` sequence. (Fast insertion into `pairs` is also desirable, but not as important as fast lookup).

The first thing that comes to mind is bisecting a sorted collection with efficient random access, but I'm not sure which data structures in Clojure are most appropriate to the task. Suggestions?

Comment: Your example code does not work as advertised. Which is the prefix, target-str or the map key?

Comment: @JustinKramer Oops. The map key is the prefix; the example call was incorrect. Fixed. (The prefix-match function given is what I'm actually using in production code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An efficient, terse approach is to take advantage of `rsubseq`, which works on any type implementing `clojure.lang.Sorted` -- which includes `sorted-map`.

```
(defn prefix-match [sorted-map target]
  (let [[closest-match value] (first (rsubseq sorted-map <= target))]
    (if closest-match
      (if (.startsWith target closest-match)
        value
        nil)
      nil)))
```

This passes the relevant tests in my suite:

```
(deftest prefix-match-success
  (testing "prefix-match returns a successful match"
    (is (prefix-match (sorted-map "foo" :one "bar" :two) "foobar") :one)
    (is (prefix-match (sorted-map "foo" :one "bar" :two) "foo") :one)))

(deftest prefix-match-fail
  (testing "prefix-match returns nil on no match"
    (is (= nil (prefix-match (sorted-map "foo" :one, "bar" :two) "bazqux")))
    (is (= nil (prefix-match (sorted-map "foo" :one, "bar" :two) "zzz")))
    (is (= nil (prefix-match (sorted-map "foo" :one, "bar" :two) "aaa")))))
```

Answer (score 21):

How about a trie?

```
(defn build-trie [seed & kvs]
  (reduce
   (fn [trie [k v]]
     (assoc-in trie (concat k [:val]) v))
   seed
   (partition 2 kvs)))

(defn prefix-match [target trie]
  (when (seq target)
    (when-let [node (trie (first target))]
      (or (:val node)
          (recur (rest target) node)))))
```

Usage:

```
user> (def trie (build-trie {} "foo" :baz "meh" :qux))
#'user/trie
user> trie
{\m {\e {\h {:val :qux}}}, \f {\o {\o {:val :baz}}}}
user> (prefix-match "foobar" trie)
:baz
user> (prefix-match "foo" trie)
:baz
user> (prefix-match "f" trie)
nil
user> (prefix-match "abcd" trie)
nil
```

Comment: Beautiful -- as easy and efficient to update as it is to build. Thanks!

Comment: FYI -- I'm not accepting this because building one's own structure when the standard library has something available out-of-the-box with better memory efficiency (and comparable-to-better performance) is a bit silly. It's still very much worth a +1, though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems simplest to just turn the list of prefixes into a regular expression, and feed those into a regex matcher, which is optimized for exactly this sort of task. Something like

```
(java.util.regex.Pattern/compile (str "^"
                                      "(?:"
                                      (clojure.string/join "|"
                                                           (map #(java.util.regex.Pattern/quote %)
                                                                prefixes))
                                      ")"))
```

Should get you a regex suitable for testing against a string (but I haven't tested it at all, so maybe I got some method names wrong or something).

Comment: Nice approach -- for long prefixes, I could see this being considerably more efficient than the trie approach on search (though it'd be interesting to benchmark). On the other hand, the trie approach would seem likely to have better performance on adding new prefix/result mappings to the list, particularly once that map has grown large.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution finds the longest matching prefix and works surprisingly well when the map is huge and strings are relatively short. It tries to match e.g. "foobar", "fooba", "foob", "foo", "fo", "f" in order and returns the first match.

```
(defn prefix-match
  [s m]
  (->> (for [end (range (count s) 0 -1)] (.subSequence s 0 end)) ; "foo", "fo", "f"
       (map m)           ; match "foo", match "fo", ...
       (remove nil?)     ; ignore unmatched
       (first)))         ; Take first and longest match
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm curious to benchmark it against the sorted-map approach; curious as to when either of them is better. (My intuition is that this is faster when you'd be creating the sorted-map transiently for the operation, and that the sorted-map approach is faster when the data structure is reused, but that's really just a guess).